# Rails seeds.rb: How can I skip multiple callbacks using Class.skip_callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, arguments, activesupport

In my `seeds.rb` file I'm creating multiple objects of class Job. Job has these callbacks:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
...
after_create :notify_by_email, :notify_by_text
...
end
```

I want to avoid generating these emails or text messages in development and staging (development currently users LetterOpener and it's a pain to have these emails popping up in my browser. I just want to be able to run `rake db:seed` and ignore the terminal). In another question on StackOverflow I found out that I can use this:

`Job.skip_callback(:create, :after, :notify_by_email)`

So I tried the following to skip both callbacks in one line:

`Job.skip_callback(:create, :after, { :notify_by_email, :notify_by_text })`

However, this threw an error. I checked the [ActiveSupport API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_callback) but it doesn't indicate a way to do what I'm trying to do, so I resorted to this:

```
  Job.skip_callback(:create, :after, :notify_by_email)
  Job.skip_callback(:create, :after, :notify_by_text)
```

Is there a way to do this more like the above attempt with a hash of callbacks?

Answer (score 3):

You may be confusing skip_before_filter (and it's similar cousins in controllers).

You can skip the after_create by adding a :if or :unless option

```
after_create :notify_by_email, if: :new_user

def new_user
  # logic to determine if user is new
end
```

**I would also recommend moving your email sending to a controller and avoid the whole issue.**

Comment: Thanks. This might be what I need, though the condition that needs to be met for the callbacks not to fire is that the objects are being created through the `seeds.rb` file. I guess I could make the method be something that tests `Rails.env.development?` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `reset_callbacks`

```
Job.reset_callbacks(:create)
```

See this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/reset_callbacks

Comment: This looks similar to what I need but I think it's perhaps too powerful because it removes all callbacks. I have some `after_create` callbacks that I want to happy when the objects are created via `seeds.rb` but not all